# Автоматизация Apache-редиректов

Tags: .htaccess, apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

**Описание:** имеется веб-приложение, развернутое на Apache. Назначение приложения - осуществлять редиректы. Оно представляет собой множество директорий с .htaccess-файлами, в которых и прописаны редиректы посредством, в основном, **mod_rewrite.**
Собственно, проблема: когда появляется новый редирект, каждый раз нужно писать тесты, прописывать вручную все правила в .htaccess. Стоит задача как-то упростить или автоматизировать данный процесс.
Может у кого-то есть опыт решения подобных проблем?
И вообще как такие проблемы решаются на крупных сайтах?

Comment: Я бы на perl или php написал бы единственный скрипт, который бы в .htaccess сказал выполнять для любых url. И этот скрипт анализируя преданный url и возможно сверяя с базой данных выдавал бы редиректы